# Designing an Objective-C class to be testable

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, testing, mocking

**Background**

I work mostly with Java. Here's some code I've written in Objective-C. My goal is to write some unit tests for "MyService". FYI: the name of the class in this code is just a placeholder.

**Question**

Does this seem like a reasonable approach? I am:

- Giving this class a singleton method (`sharedMyService`)
- Declaring a constructor to inject `NSURLSession`
- Incorporating a default constructor that uses the real `NSURLSession`

My intent is:

- I want to test this code by mocking `NSURLSession`
- I would inject that `NSURLSession` mock into this class to test it
- Probably read more on the Apple docs or somewhere to see how to mock the `dataTaskWithURL:` method.

Here is the header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyService : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSURLSession *session;

+ (id)sharedMyService;

- (instancetype)initWithURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session;

- (void)fetchData:(NSString*)location;

@end
```

And the implementation...

```
#import "MyService.h"

@implementation MyService

static NSString *const targetUri = @"http://something.com/%@";

+ (instancetype)sharedMyService {
    static MyService *service = nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (service == nil) {
            service = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return service;
}

- (instancetype)initWithURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.session = session;
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithURLSession:[NSURLSession sharedSession]];
}

- (NSURLSession *)getSession {
    return self.session;
}

- (void)fetchData:(NSString*)location {
    NSURL *targetUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:targetUri, location]];
    NSURLSession *urlSession = [self getSession];
    NSURLSessionTask *sessionTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithURL:targetUrl completionHandler: ^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Request succeeded.");
    }];
    [sessionTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to think about:

- In my opinion, designing iOS code (Objective-C or Swift) is no different to designing code in Java. The same principles apply and you would do it the same way.
- Avoid singletons wherever possible. For example, you could still have a accessor on the class to return your service, but also have a method that can clear, reset or inject a new instance. Pure singleton patterns are a pain in the testing rear end and singletons are often overuse in many iOS projects. In my code, even though I could code up singletons, I generally make them settable as well (Even if only from a category in the unit testing source code).
- Look into the [OCMock](http://ocmock.org) Objective-C mocking framework. I've used it for many years and there is very little it cannot do. Very similar to Java frameworks like Easymock and Mockito. Note though that if you are thinking of using Swift, that mocking for Swift is pretty much nonexistent. Swift simply doesn't have the runtime capabilities to do it.

Answer (score 0):

"Does this seem like a reasonable approach?" Yes (though we have no idea what your tests aim to prove or how your other code will use this class).

There are obviously other options, like using a subclass to enable additional testability. The benefit here being that you don't confuse users by publicly declaring the class as a singleton and an instantiable class.

Also think about whether a singleton is really the right approach for you - do you ever want to be able to reuse this class with different sessions - and whether a factory approach would be better...

Comment: Thanks @josh-caswell just checked the meaning of my misspelling :-S

Comment: Huh, I didn't even know it was a word! :)